# How can I have an Excel VBA application in use without multiuser lock?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an app I coded in Excel that suits the needs of my project; it serves the purpose of keeping track of quite a lengthy process and prerequisites and such.

It feeds off of a certain number of tables in my file.

The thing is, only one user can currently work on that file; and since we have multiple teams working on different parts in parallel, it would be nice to host that somehow in a way that would remove the single-user restriction.

Do any of you have an idea of how I could work around this?

Comment: Shared workbook

Comment: I would not recommend using shared workbook. They tend to corrupt very fast. I would recommend you use excel as a front end and save the data in an access db hosted on a shared drive. BTW this question may get closed very soon as  "opinion based..."

Comment: I figured, but I can't find a place where I could ask such questions

Comment: This is currently a little too broad to answer (though I would argue not necessarily opinion-based -- many questions are open-ended such that different solutions could work). How frequently do users need to **save** the Excel file *at the same time*? Do you have access to Office 365 in your environment? OneDrive? SharePoint?

Comment: It's a big company, we do have office 365 and sharepoint environments. We are trying out tomorrow if co-authirung works with vba on our environment.

Comment: @Saryk Well I just recalled you can't use VBA in an online environment, so you can't do editing in Excel Online... but I do have one solution I'll write up in an answer. Before I can do that, though, I still need an answer to my first question: how frequently (if ever) do users need to *save* the Excel file at the same time? (I'm talking a window of a few seconds)

Comment: I can't answer that right now, I'll check tomorrow.

Comment: Also, look at using a database, like access, this will be set up to handle things like this.

Comment: It's less about saving it often or at the same time than being able to work on it simultaneously, and have it update in real time.

I expect half a dozen people will be working on it, and saving it whenever but not that often, and not necessarily at the same time.

Answer (score -1):

I worked on a solution for a very similar project of keeping track of a hospital's labor utilization (nursing employee census, if you will) on a day-to-day basis across every nursing-based department in the hospital system. This solution relies on a couple conditions:

1. That it will be unlikely two or more people will need to *save* data to the final file at the same time (meaning within seconds of each other).
2. All the various users of the file will have access to at least one commonly-shared network drive or location.

In our case, we created a new file each day, but it wouldn't be difficult to adjust the data-writing code to append data, rather than create a new file and dump data into that new file.

The rough outline of the process is this:

- Create a read-only destination file (.xlsx in our case) in a network location that contains tables of data split between `n` worksheets.
- Create an interactive form (.xlsm) that allows user input and then on form submission, opens the destination .xlsx file and saves the form data to it, then closes it. This interactive .xlsm file can be placed in the same network location, with shortcuts created on as many peoples' desktops (or departmental shares, for example) as necessary.

With the speed of Excel and VBA, this means you're only "opening" the destination file for a second or two to write the form data, no matter how long one user may have a copy of the form open.

One thing that will be necessary is to check if the file is open, and gracefully alert the user if they need to try again, which you can do with a function covering the related error codes, for example:

```
Function IsFileOpen(FileName As String)

    Dim iFilenum As Long
    Dim iError As Long
    On Error Resume Next    
    iFilenum = FreeFile()   
    Open FileName For Input Lock Read As #iFilenum
    Close iFilenum          
    iError = Err              
    On Error GoTo 0         

    Select Case iError        
        Case 0:    IsFileOpen = False
        Case 70:   IsFileOpen = True
        Case 53:   IsFileOpen = "Not Found"
        Case Else: Error iError   
    End Select

End Function
```

which can be called via some code like (pseudo code):

```
Private Sub UpdateData(ByVal thesheet As String)
    Dim xlApp As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlWkbk As New Excel.Workbook

    If Not IsFileOpen(FileName) Then
       Set xlWkbk = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(filename)
       xlWkbk.Worksheets(theSheet).Activate
    Else
        MsgBox "Sorry, the file is currently in use. Please try again", vbOKOnly
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Or you could have it simply wait a few seconds (e.g. `Wait 5`) or more if the writing process doesn't cover that much data. The specific amount of seconds to wait would depend on testing write times based on your scenario and your data. That would be added as a nested `If Not` statement inside the previous one.

Then, when the result is that the file is not in use, simply write a series of subroutines to write the form data (stored as variables) to the destination sheet. End with something like

```
xlWkbk.Save
xlWkbk.Close
Set xlWkbk = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
```

to save and close the workbook and clear your variables (memory cleanup and all that).

You may already be aware of this practice, but while you'll want to keep Excel visible during development, you'll definitely want to set `Application.Visible = False` on the production files for two reasons:

1. This will prevent users from getting confused by a lot of automation
2. It covers `Application.Updating` as well, which will *really* speed up data processing.

Comment: How does this handle real-time data changes ? If team A is working on part A and team B on part B, there could be situations where B could need prerequisites validated by A ; I guess we'd need to reload the data.
It's a checklist for deploying applications and checking they work and all, so we have one file saved per application. We'll check it out, thanks !

Comment: @Saryk This implementation is designed to abstract the data entry step *away* from the file that contains the data so folks *don't* deal with real-time conflicts. If your folks have a need to see inputted data from other people in real time for some reason, then this probably won't work for that scenario. Excel isn't designed that way, at least not in tandem with VBA. I'd recommend using MS Access, with either an internal file storage structure, a link to an Excel file, or a link to a SQL database (preferred). Access is designed to be a multi-user environment, and it supports VBA, of course.

Comment: I am absolutely not familiar with access but I'm sure some coworkers are. We'll find a way, thank you for your input !

Comment: @Saryk You can see http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=102281&seqNum=3 or https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-or-link-to-data-in-an-excel-workbook-a1952878-7c58-47b1-893d-e084913cc958#__link_to_data to see how to link (**not** import) Excel spreadsheets to an Access DB frontend of forms. Just keep in mind that whichever implementation you end up going with, if it involves Excel, you probably don't want multiple users to be manually/directly opening the Excel file with the actual data in it at the same time.